# Was my Raspi hacked?

Tags: pi-3, networking, login, logfiles

I was using my Raspi 3B as a home temperature station and astrophotography module. However, 18th of January it just stopped working. Couldn't connect to the network and also some of the commands were not working (e.g. ls, cat, mv, cp, rm). I have checked logs connecting sd card to other computer and noticed that everything started at 1 pm local time:

```
Jan 18 12:36:33 raspberrypi ntpd_intres[500]: host name not found: 3.debian.pool.ntp.org
Jan 18 12:52:36 raspberrypi ntpd_intres[500]: host name not found: 0.debian.pool.ntp.org
Jan 18 12:52:36 raspberrypi ntpd_intres[500]: host name not found: 1.debian.pool.ntp.org
Jan 18 12:52:36 raspberrypi ntpd_intres[500]: host name not found: 2.debian.pool.ntp.org
Jan 18 12:52:36 raspberrypi ntpd_intres[500]: host name not found: 3.debian.pool.ntp.org
Jan 18 13:01:12 raspberrypi dhcpcd[364]: eth0: carrier acquired
Jan 18 13:01:12 raspberrypi dhcpcd[364]: eth0: IAID eb:8a:93:3b
Jan 18 13:01:12 raspberrypi dhcpcd[364]: eth0: soliciting an IPv6 router
Jan 18 13:01:13 raspberrypi dhcpcd[364]: eth0: soliciting a DHCP lease
Jan 18 13:01:15 raspberrypi ntpd[490]: Listen normally on 4 eth0 fe80::a04d:2f17:fe17:3f98 UDP 123
Jan 18 13:01:15 raspberrypi ntpd[490]: peers refreshed
Jan 18 13:01:17 raspberrypi ntpd_intres[500]: host name not found: 0.debian.pool.ntp.org
Jan 18 13:01:17 raspberrypi ntpd_intres[500]: host name not found: 1.debian.pool.ntp.org
Jan 18 13:01:17 raspberrypi ntpd_intres[500]: host name not found: 2.debian.pool.ntp.org
Jan 18 13:01:17 raspberrypi ntpd_intres[500]: host name not found: 3.debian.pool.ntp.org
Jan 18 13:01:18 raspberrypi dhcpcd[364]: eth0: probing for an IPv4LL address
Jan 18 13:01:23 raspberrypi dhcpcd[364]: eth0: using IPv4LL address 169.254.146.171
Jan 18 13:01:23 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[339]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface eth0.IPv4 with address 169.254.146.171.
Jan 18 13:01:23 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[339]: New relevant interface eth0.IPv4 for mDNS.
Jan 18 13:01:23 raspberrypi dhcpcd[364]: eth0: adding route to 169.254.0.0/16
Jan 18 13:01:23 raspberrypi avahi-daemon[339]: Registering new address record for 169.254.146.171 on eth0.IPv4.
Jan 18 13:01:25 raspberrypi ntpd[490]: Listen normally on 5 eth0 169.254.146.171 UDP 123
Jan 18 13:01:25 raspberrypi ntpd[490]: peers refreshed
Jan 18 13:01:26 raspberrypi dhcpcd[364]: eth0: no IPv6 Routers available
Jan 18 13:01:27 raspberrypi ntpd_intres[500]: host name not found: 0.debian.pool.ntp.org
Jan 18 13:01:27 raspberrypi ntpd_intres[500]: host name not found: 1.debian.pool.ntp.org
Jan 18 13:01:27 raspberrypi ntpd_intres[500]: host name not found: 2.debian.pool.ntp.org
Jan 18 13:01:27 raspberrypi ntpd_intres[500]: host name not found: 3.debian.pool.ntp.org
Jan 18 07:48:33 raspberrypi systemd[110]: Failed at step EXEC spawning /bin/kmod: No such file or directory
Jan 18 07:48:33 raspberrypi systemd-modules-load[118]: Inserted module 'fuse'
Jan 18 07:48:33 raspberrypi systemd-modules-load[118]: Inserted module 'i2c_dev'
Jan 18 07:48:33 raspberrypi systemd-modules-load[118]: Failed to find module 'w1-gpio pullup=1'
Jan 18 07:48:33 raspberrypi systemd-modules-load[118]: Inserted module 'w1_therm'
Jan 18 07:48:33 raspberrypi systemd-modules-load[118]: Inserted module 'i2c_bcm2708'
Jan 18 07:48:33 raspberrypi systemd-modules-load[118]: Failed to find module 'spi-bcm2708'
Jan 18 07:48:33 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting Create Static Device Nodes in /dev...
Jan 18 07:48:33 raspberrypi systemd-modules-load[118]: Inserted module 'snd_bcm2835'
Jan 18 07:48:33 raspberrypi systemd-modules-load[118]: Inserted module 'lirc_dev'
Jan 18 07:48:33 raspberrypi systemd-modules-load[118]: Failed to find module 'lirc_rpi gpio_out_pin=7'
```

At the end you can see that I have restarted Rpi, and because the clock was restarted it showed 7 am. What do you think about it? Are there any other logs which can tell me something more? I already checked auth.log and it is not showing any suspicious behavior. Rpi was running without any issues over a year and suddenly this happened. I am curious what do you think.

Cheers!

Comment: First glance it looks like the RPi IP address lease expired.  When it requested a renewal from DHCP it didn't get any response so it defaulted to its own which is the 169.254.x.x.  I'd look at your router logs to see what went wrong.

Comment: "commands were not working" - What error messages you got?

Comment: @Fabian command not found error 2